# output 2d array into html file

Tags: javascript

I have a project to do for school where you make a memory game. The grid is a 6x6 and is arranged in a table. What I'm trying to do is when the user clicks the "print" button, the table fills up with the numbers in the 2d array. I have created the array with numbers in them, but I can't get them to output to the table in the HTML file.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <link href = "matchinggame.css" rel = "stylesheet"/>


</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell00" ></td>
            <td id="cell01" ></td>
            <td id="cell02" ></td>
            <td id="cell03" ></td>
            <td id="cell04" ></td>
            <td id="cell05" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell10" ></td>
            <td id="cell11" ></td>
            <td id="cell12" ></td>
            <td id="cell13" ></td>
            <td id="cell14" ></td>
            <td id="cell15" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell20" ></td>
            <td id="cell21" ></td>
            <td id="cell22" ></td>
            <td id="cell23" ></td>
            <td id="cell24" ></td>
            <td id="cell25" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell30" ></td>
            <td id="cell31" ></td>
            <td id="cell32" ></td>
            <td id="cell33" ></td>
            <td id="cell34" ></td>
            <td id="cell35" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell40" ></td>
            <td id="cell41" ></td>
            <td id="cell42" ></td>
            <td id="cell43" ></td>
            <td id="cell44" ></td>
            <td id="cell45" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell50" ></td>
            <td id="cell51" ></td>
            <td id="cell52" ></td>
            <td id="cell53" ></td>
            <td id="cell54" ></td>
            <td id="cell55" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="print" id = "button1" onclick="drawBoard();">
    </div>


</body>
```

```
root {
    display: block;
}

body {
    text-align:center;
}

p {
    font-family:monospace;
}

table {
    margin:auto;
}

td {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

JS:

```
var board = [["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"],
        ["4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6"],
        ["7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9"],
        ["10", "10", "11", "11", "12", "12"],
        ["13", "13", "14", "14", "15", "15"],
        ["16", "16", "17", "17", "18", "18"]];



    function drawBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < board.length; i++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; j++) {
                var cell = document.getElementById("cell" + row + col);
                cell.innerHTML = board[row][col];
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ran your code in my browser, which outputted a few errors I fixed. Here's the working code:

```
var board = [["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"],
        ["4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6"],
        ["7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9"],
        ["10", "10", "11", "11", "12", "12"],
        ["13", "13", "14", "14", "15", "15"],
        ["16", "16", "17", "17", "18", "18"]];



    function drawBoard() {
        for (var row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
                var cell = document.getElementById("cell" + row + col);
                cell.innerHTML = board[row][col];
        }

    }
}
```

The things I fixed were:

- You were using `int` instead of `var` to declare row/col in your for loops. JavaScript doesn't have any types.
- You were incrementing i/j instead of row/col.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did it in Java first and then copied it and I totally forgot about  the typing. Appreciate it.

Comment: "JavaScript doesn't have any types"—actually it does have types, `int`, `float`, `boolean`, `string`, etc. The difference is that JavaScript is a [loosely typed](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/l/looslang.htm) language whereas Java is a [strongly typed](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/strolang.htm) language.

Comment: It doesn't have explicit types.

Answer (score 2):

This works and more elegant :

```
board.forEach((row, i) => 
   row.forEach((item, j) => {
      document.getElementById("cell" + i + j).innerHTML = item
   })
)
```

[image]

```js
var board = [["1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3"],
        ["4", "4", "5", "5", "6", "6"],
        ["7", "7", "8", "8", "9", "9"],
        ["10", "10", "11", "11", "12", "12"],
        ["13", "13", "14", "14", "15", "15"],
        ["16", "16", "17", "17", "18", "18"]];


board.forEach((row, i) => 
   row.forEach((item, j) => {
      document.getElementById("cell" + i + j).innerHTML = item
   })
)
```

```css
root {
    display: block;
}

body {
    text-align:center;
}

p {
    font-family:monospace;
}

table {
    margin:auto;
}

td {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell00" ></td>
            <td id="cell01" ></td>
            <td id="cell02" ></td>
            <td id="cell03" ></td>
            <td id="cell04" ></td>
            <td id="cell05" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell10" ></td>
            <td id="cell11" ></td>
            <td id="cell12" ></td>
            <td id="cell13" ></td>
            <td id="cell14" ></td>
            <td id="cell15" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell20" ></td>
            <td id="cell21" ></td>
            <td id="cell22" ></td>
            <td id="cell23" ></td>
            <td id="cell24" ></td>
            <td id="cell25" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell30" ></td>
            <td id="cell31" ></td>
            <td id="cell32" ></td>
            <td id="cell33" ></td>
            <td id="cell34" ></td>
            <td id="cell35" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell40" ></td>
            <td id="cell41" ></td>
            <td id="cell42" ></td>
            <td id="cell43" ></td>
            <td id="cell44" ></td>
            <td id="cell45" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="cell50" ></td>
            <td id="cell51" ></td>
            <td id="cell52" ></td>
            <td id="cell53" ></td>
            <td id="cell54" ></td>
            <td id="cell55" ></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div>
        <input type="button" value="print" id = "button1" onclick="drawBoard();">
    </div>


</body>
```